# Terminal: grep command usage with '[' character as target, not function

Tags: terminal

Im using the `grep` command In a simple script, the problem however Is that the string which the grep command Is searching for includes a square bracket character: `[`.

After some research, i have found that the square bracket `[` character is in fact used as a function for optimising the grep commands output through a process called "`pipelining`" (Although don't quote me on It as Im not sure).

My Question:

**How do I search for a string with a '[' character in it without invoking a pipelining function within grep?**

Elaboration:

The script Is searching a system log for the string `su[`. This Is my current malfunctioning command: `tail -1 system.log | grep " su["`, however It will not work due to the square bracket at the end, returning the error: `grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced`.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: escape `[` with `\ `. It'll look like: `grep " su\["`.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, Add it as an answer, with explanation of why special characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets should be escaped with `\`, because it's a special character. Your command will look like:

```
tail -1 system.log | grep " su\["
```

### Special characters

From this [site](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) You can learn about special characters in bash.

> What makes a character special? If it has a meaning beyond its literal meaning, a meta-meaning, then we refer to it as a special character. Along with commands and keywords, special characters are building blocks of Bash scripts.

`\` is a special character and it could be used as:

> **[ ]**
>   test.
>
> Test expression between [ ].  Note that [ is part of the shell builtin test (and a synonym for it), not a link to the external command /usr/bin/test.
>
> **[[ ]]**
>   test.
>
> Test expression between [[ ]]. More flexible than the single-bracket [ ] test, this is a shell keyword.
>
> **[ ]**
>   array element.
>
> In the context of an array, brackets set off the numbering of each element of that array.
>   `Array[1]=slot_1`
>
> `echo ${Array[1]}`
>
> **[ ]**
>   range of characters.
>
> As part of a regular expression, brackets delineate a range of characters to match.
>
> **$[ ... ]**
>   integer expansion.
>
> Evaluate integer expression between $[ ].

Comment: Yeah this worked with a simple modification
( tail -1 system.log | grep " su\\\[" ), necessitating an extra backslash (\\) for some reason to work properly, however you were on the right track, thank you.